# Find where array contains value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, coffeescript

Let's say you have boxes with items. Each item may be in more than one box, so every item has an array of ids to boxes that the item lies in.

childA= {...boxIds: ['000001', '000002', '000003']...}

In mongodb you can say `child.find({boxIds:'000002'})` to get childA and every other children where 000002 is in the array of boxIds.
This is what I tried in mongoose (coffeescript):

```
  data = boxIds: box._id
  Child.find data, (err, children) -> doSomething
```

I always get an empty result though. I can't find the problem or is this type of query not supported by mongoose?

**EDIT**

```
Child = new mongoose.Schema
  ...
  boxIds: Array
  ...
```

box._id is the normal mongodb id string

example query in mongodb: `db.child.find( {boxIds: '50bb5d10ba1e232401000002'} )`

result: `......., "boxIds" : [ "50bb5d10ba1e232401000002" ], .....`

**EDIT2**

Could it be that _id is not a string?

Comment: Mongoose can support any query that MongoDB can support.  Often, an empty result problem like yours comes down to the types in the schema not matching what's in the database.  Can you add your schema and example docs to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `box._id` is an ObjectId, but the `boxIds` array field of `Child` contains strings.

Try this instead:

```
data = boxIds: box._id.toString()
Child.find data, (err, children) -> doSomething
```

The other option would be to define `boxIds` as a string array in the schema and then Mongoose will do the necessary casting for you:

```
Child = new mongoose.Schema
  ...
  boxIds: [String]
  ...
```

Comment: Yes, totally, I decided to go the other way around and define my schema like this: boxIds: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]. Casting is also done automaticly. Thank you!